# Proof of orthogonality of unit vectors in orthogonal curvilinear coordinate system

Tags: calculus

### Context

Suppose $\mathbf{R}(q_1,q_2,q_3)=\mathbf{r}(x,y,z)$ represents a position vector in physical space in a curvilinear coordinate system defined by $q_i=q_i(x,y,z)$ for $i=1,2,3$. The reverse mapping $x=x(q_1,q_2,q_3)$ (similarly for $y$ and $z$) also exists.

The curvilinear system is orthogonal if, at the intersection point of the planes $q_i=\text{constant}$, the normals of these planes are mutually perpendicular. So, at any point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
\begin{align}
\nabla q_1\cdot\nabla q_2=0=\nabla q_2\cdot\nabla q_3=\nabla q_3\cdot\nabla q_1. \tag{1}
\end{align}

The unit vectors ($\mathbf{e}_i$) are defined as
\begin{align}
\mathbf{u}_i=&\ \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}}{\partial q_i},\\
\mathbf{e}_i=\frac{\mathbf{u}_i}{\lVert\mathbf{u}_i\rVert}=&\ \frac{\partial \mathbf{r}/\partial q_i}{\lVert\partial \mathbf{r}/\partial q_i\rVert}.
\end{align}

### Question

Prove that $\mathbf{e}_i\cdot\mathbf{e}_j=\delta_{ij}$ (Kronecker Delta).

### Note

One can either prove

1. $\mathbf{u}_i\times\nabla q_i=\mathbf{0}$ (i.e.; $\mathbf{u}_i$ is parallel to $\nabla q_i$) so that orthogonality follows from eq. (1),
2. Or, prove that $\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\nabla q_j=0$ for $i\neq j$

Using method 2, one way could be to consider
$$\text{d}q_1=1\,\text{d}q_1+0\,\text{d}q_2+0\,\text{d}q_3=\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\text{d}x + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\text{d}y + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial z}\text{d}z. \tag{2}$$
Expanding $\text{d}x$ as
$$\text{d}x=\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1}\text{d}q_1 + \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2}\text{d}q_2 + \frac{\partial x}{\partial q_3}\text{d}q_3,$$
and substituting back in eq. (2) along with similar expansions for $\text{d}y$ and $\text{d}z$, it can be shown by equating coefficients of $\text{d}q_i$ in eq. (2) that
$$1=\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_1} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial q_1} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial q_1}=\nabla q_1\cdot\mathbf{u}_1,\\
0=\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_2} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial q_2} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial q_2}=\nabla q_1\cdot\mathbf{u}_2,\\
0=\frac{\partial q_1}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial q_3} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial q_3} + \frac{\partial q_1}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial q_3}=\nabla q_1\cdot\mathbf{u}_3.$$

Similarly proceeding with $\text{d}q_2$ and $\text{d}q_3$ proves the result. But this analysis could be done for **any** curvilinear system. Where was assumption of orthogonal curvilinear system (eq. (1)) invoked? What is wrong in this proof?

### Edit

Thanks to [Kenny Wong's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3052849/456996) for pointing out that

1. The relation $\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\nabla q_j=\delta_{ij}$ holds true in any curvilinear coordinate system (need not be orthogonal). There is nothing wrong with the proof shown in the question. It only proves $\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\nabla q_j=\delta_{ij}$ but not that $\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\mathbf{u}_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.
2. For an orthogonal curvilinear coordinate system, this result ($\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\nabla q_j=\delta_{ij}$) along with eq. (1) proves that $\mathbf{u}_i$ is parallel to $\nabla q_i$ and hence $\mathbf{u}_i\cdot\mathbf{u}_j=0$ for $i\neq j$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source of the confusion is that $\mathbf{ u}_i $ and $\nabla q_i $ are not the same thing. They are not necessarily even parallel!

Let me give you an example. We'll work in two dimensions, with
$$ q_1 = x + y, \ \ \ q_2 = y.$$

Inverting this, we get

$$ x = q_1 - q_2, \ \ \ y = q_2.$$

So
$$ \mathbf{u}_1 = (1, 0), \ \ \ \mathbf{u}_2 = (-1, 1),$$
$$ \nabla q_1 = (1, 1), \ \ \ \nabla q_2 = (0, 1).$$
As you can see the $\mathbf{u}_i$'s are not the same as the $\nabla q_i$'s, not even up to scaling!

It is true that
$$ \mathbf{u}_i . \nabla q_j = \delta_{ij},$$
as you correctly proved in your question.

But you're interested in something different: you're interested in whether or not $\mathbf{u}_i . \mathbf u_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$. And since the $\mathbf{u}_i$'s are not parallel to the $\nabla q_i$'s, we simply can't tell whether or not $\mathbf{u}_i . \mathbf u_j = 0$ for $i \neq j$, knowing only that $\mathbf{u}_i . \nabla q_j = \delta_{ij}$.

I believe people call $\{ \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \}$ the "original" basis and $\{ \nabla q_1, \nabla q_2 \}$ the "dual" basis. They are two different bases, as this example shows.

---

Returning to the original question, I think the thing to do is to show that $\mathbf{u}_i$ and $\nabla q_i$ *are* the same, up to scaling, *on the condition that the coordinates are orthogonal*.

This is actually quite easy to do. Let's write

$$ \mathbf{u}_1 = c_1 \nabla q_1 + c_2 \nabla q_2,$$

where $c_1, c_2$ are cooefficients that we must determine.

If we dot both sides with $\nabla q_1$, or with $\nabla q_2$, we get

$$ 1 = \mathbf{u}_1 . \nabla q_1 = c_1 \nabla q_1 . \nabla q_1 + c_2 \nabla q_2 . \nabla q_1  = c_1 \| \nabla q_1\|^2$$

$$ 0 =  \mathbf{u}_1 . \nabla q_2 = c_1 \nabla q_1 . \nabla q_2 + c_2 \nabla q_2 . \nabla q_2  = c_2 \| \nabla q_2\|^2 $$

Let me clarify what I've just done:

- On the left hand side, I used the relations $\mathbf{u_i} . \nabla q_j = \delta_{ij}$ which you proved in generality for all coordinate systems.
- On the right hand side, I used the fact that $\nabla q_1 . \nabla q_2 = 0$, which is true only for an orthogonal choice of coodinates.

Anyway, this exercise tells us that $c_1 = 1 / \| \nabla q_1 \|^2$ and $c_2 = 0$, so

$$ \mathbf{u}_1 = \frac{\nabla q_1}{\| \nabla q_1 \|^2}.$$

And if we do the same for $\mathbf{u}_2$, we get

$$ \mathbf{u}_2 = \frac{\nabla q_2}{\| \nabla q_2 \|^2}.$$

So, under the assumption that the coordinates are orthogonal, we find that the two sets of basis vectors  $\{ \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \}$ and $\{\nabla q_1, \nabla q_2 \}$ are the same thing, up to rescaling. Since $\{\nabla q_1, \nabla q_2 \}$  is an orthogonal basis by assumption, it must follow that $\{ \mathbf{u}_1, \mathbf{u}_2 \}$ is orthogonal too.

Comment: Excellent! Sorry for the late response. I will clarify things in my question.